# UnsupportedAudioFileException при попытке проиграть аудио

Tags: java, аудио

```
URL file = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("audio/1.wav").toURI().toURL();
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(stream);
clip.setFramePosition(0);
clip.start();
```

На второй строке вылетает ошибка:

> javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL

Этот пример взят из [Хабрахабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191422/).

Пробовал еще так:

```
Clip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
clip.play();
```

В этом коде ошибок не возникает, но и аудио не проигрывается.

Как проиграть это аудио?

Comment: втором варианте вы не открыли аудио
         clip.open();

Answer (score 1):

```
public void playSound() {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("1.wav"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И убедитесь, что звуковой файл лежит в необходимой папке.

Comment: Владимир, вам стоит пересмотреть стратегию проверок. [Что нам делать с роборевьюерами?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Спасибо, что указали на недостаток. Действительно увлекся без меры.

Answer (score 0):

В первой версии он не может найти файл. Думаю нужно проверить путь

В втором версии пробовали с начало открыть аудио?

```
clip.open();
clip.start();
```

Comment: Классы которые подключаю, и тут нету метода open();

    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.applet.AudioClip;